# How to use XPath extract text without Html tag?

Tags: xpath

```
<div id="info" class="">
<span>
  <span class="pl"> author</span>:
    <a class="" href="/search/author"Peter</a>
</span><br/>
<span class="pl">publisher:</span> god cor<br/>
<span class="pl">year:</span> 2011-6<br/>
<span class="pl">page:</span> 360<br/>
<span class="pl">price:</span> 39.50<br/>
```

From the above HTML tags, i want to extract those numbers with XPath.How can i do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XPath for each number is (in order as shown above) :

```
//*[@id="info"]/a/text()[2]         --> 2011-6
//*[@id="info"]/a/text()[3]         -->360
//*[@id="info"]/a/text()[4]         --> 39.5
```

You can know the XPath for any tag by just opening the html file in Chrome, right clicking on the view and choosing "inspect". When you find the tag you want, just right click on it and choose Copy-> Copy XPath.